# Insert a row in another table for each row in another table that meets a criteria

Tags: sql-server, insert

I need to insert a new row into one table `CUSTOMER_NOTES`for each row in another table `CUSTOMER` that meets a condition.

If `CUSTOMER` table column `CURRENT` is marked as 1, then I need to shove a note into the `CUSTOMER_NOTES` table, like "THIS IS A CURRENT CUSTOMER". So, if there are 50 current customers (and 240 total customers), there would be 50 entries shoved into the `CUSTOMER_NOTES` table with the VALUE being "THIS IS A CURRENT CUSTOMER".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `CUSTOMER` and `CUSTOMER_NOTES` has a column `CUSTOMER_ID`:

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_NOTES(
    CUSTOMER_ID, 
    NOTES
)
SELECT
    CUSTOMER_ID,
    'THIS IS A CURRENT CUSTOMER'
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE
    [CURRENT] = 1
```

Comment: This is completely valid. There's probably more at play than just this part of the example, but if this were the entirety of the problem, you could alternatively add a computed column to the Customer table conditioned on the value of [Current]